# Add multiple properties at once, to object which already has some properties defined

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add multiple properties at once without overwriting the properties which are already inside object?

```
object = {prop1: "1", prop1: "2", prop3: "3"};
//Want to add: {prop4: "4", prop5: "5", prop6: "6"}
```

Is there any way to do this without iterating over the properties I want to add and adding one by one?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Object [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
object = {prop1: "1", prop1: "2", prop3: "3"};
//Want to add: {prop4: "4", prop5: "5", prop6: "6"} 

Object.assign(object, {prop4: "4", prop5: "5", prop6: "6"})
console.log(object)
```

Comment: Great! Is it going to respect the order, won't add new properties before the ones that already exist inside object?

Comment: @juniorjunior: I didn't quite follow you, but if you meant that it won't overwrite any existing properties if they already exist, then sorry it will. And that's what a looped code will do too.